# replace/remove background image on gimp 2.6.11

Tags: images, gimp, compile

How do I remove these images by compiling gimp from source?

I can't find any file containing these images.

[image]

Comment: It is said that there are pixbuf headers in gimp source (gimp-stock-pixbufs.h,gimp-wilber-pixbufs.h, and gimp-core-pixbufs.h). but i can't imagine how they are being displayed.

Comment: Even though I now prefer SO to mailing lists I guess you might get an answer sooner on the [Gimp developer mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/gimp-developer-list)

Comment: `gimprc` has a property called `toolbox-wilber` which you can set to `no` to remove the mascot from the top of the toolbox. Perhaps you can grep the source tree for that and gain some insight or even discover an undocumented config option ;)

Answer (score 1):

They are hiding in [`/app/widgets/gimpcairo.c` at line 140](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/app/widgets/gimpcairo.c?h=gimp-2-8&id=77ac7ffa90ab9df2ccb346dcf9fc3362b0475117#n140) to the end of the file.

You should be able to comment out the contents of those functions.

If you want to get rid of the space where it uses to draw the toolbox one you can look at [these lines](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/app/widgets/gimptoolbox.c?h=gimp-2-8&id=77ac7ffa90ab9df2ccb346dcf9fc3362b0475117#n262).