# How do I remove the GIMP logo from main window background?

Tags: gimp

Is there a way to remove the GIMP logo from the background of the main window? Instructions not found at [gimp.org](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/) .

[image: GIMP Main Window]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace/remove background image on gimp 2.6.11](https://superuser.com/questions/204596/replace-remove-background-image-on-gimp-2-6-11)

Answer (score 2):

**Hide Wilber logo in background of workspace, default dark theme GIMP 2.10:**

1. Open the default theme's gtkrc file (location on mac: `/Applications/GIMP-2.10.app/Contents/Resources/share/gimp/2.0/themes/Dark/`) in a text editor.
2. Find the following code (around line 360):

   ```
   style "gimp-dark-display-style" = "gimp-dark-default-style"
   {
     GimpRuler::font-scale = 0.6444
     GimpUnitComboBox::label-scale = 0.8333
     GimpScaleComboBox::label-scale = 0.8333
     GtkComboBox::arrow-size = 8
     GtkButton::inner-border = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
     GtkButton::focus-line-width = 0
     GtkButton::focus-padding = 0
   }
   widget_class "*GimpDisplayShell.*" style "gimp-dark-display-style"
   ```
3. Within the brackets `{ }`, add this line (change the #454545 color if needed):

   ```
   fg[NORMAL] = "#454545"
   ```
4. Result:

   ```
   style "gimp-dark-display-style" = "gimp-dark-default-style"
   {
     GimpRuler::font-scale = 0.6444
     GimpUnitComboBox::label-scale = 0.8333
     GimpScaleComboBox::label-scale = 0.8333
     GtkComboBox::arrow-size = 8
     GtkButton::inner-border = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
     GtkButton::focus-line-width = 0
     GtkButton::focus-padding = 0
     fg[NORMAL] = "#454545"
   }
   widget_class "*GimpDisplayShell.*" style "gimp-dark-display-style"
   ```

This changes the color of the Wilbur element to hex #454545, which should be the same as the plain background color of the workspace. (If not, find out the hex value of your background and add that number instead.)

Answer (score 1):

See the this mailing list post: https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2018/09/msg00268.html. It will tell you how to download and install news themes that don't have the Wilber logo.

It worked for me on a Mac. I added the theme to the /Applications/GIMP-2.10.app/Contents/Resources/share/gimp/2.0/themes/ folder and then activated the theme. No more creepy, bug-eyed wolf staring back at me. See the post for where to add the theme on other OS's.